# How to enable IPv6 on an interface but disable IPv6 ND traffic

Tags: networking, ipv6

For an experiment, I am trying to disable IPv6 traffic on an interface as they cause packet-noise. I'm trying to have 0 packets generated by the interface but have IPV6 addresses configurable on it.

So I'd like to have IPv6 enabled but all Neighbor Discovery (ND) traffic like Router solicitations etc disabled. If it can't be permanent disabled, I'd like to increase the interval so that it's very rarely generated.

I tried the following configuration but still it wouldn't work as expected. What's the right flag/value for achieving this?

I've seen that disabling IPv6 completely does that but unfortunately I need IPv6 enabled.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=0

sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.router_solicitations=0
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.router_solicitations=0

sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.router_solicitation_delay=100000
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.router_solicitation_interval=100000
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.router_solicitation_max_interval=100000
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.router_probe_interval=100000
```

Comment: So would you disable ARP on IPv4-enabled networks because ARP makes noise? Doing this disrupts IPv4. No discovery means you must use a static address and all peers communicating need *also* a permanent neighbour entry for your IP. There could be other problems.

Comment: I doubt anyone took the time to code up a way to do this in your OS's IPv6 stack, because it's useless. Why would anyone want to put an IPv6 address on an interface that's being blocked from doing the low-level basic operations that allow IPv6 to work on that network segment?

Comment: This's a very special case where a scapy based test tool shall be used to send packets on veth interfaces and it would also read every packet received on them. The IPv6 ND traffic is quite noisy and would help having them disabled while still having the capability to configure IPv6 addresses on them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found the right `sysctl` invocation or kernel setting @padfoot, but I've been tasked with doing something similar recently.

One way I've found to hackily get a similar result is just dropping the icmpv6 traffic with netfilter / ip6tables.

```
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type <THE_TYPE_TO_DROP> -j DROP -o <OUTGOING_INTERFACE>
```

([Types defined here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/icmpv6-parameters/icmpv6-parameters.xhtml))